# Is there an API to do screen capture in WinUI 3?

Tags: graphics, screenshot, winui-3

I have been searching for an API to capture screen images in a WinUI 3 app (without the user selecting from a picker, as from GraphicsCaptureItem). My goal is to capture screen images under programmatic control and display them on a Canvas element. Most of what I've found so far are APIs that work only on Windows forms.

I can think of some possible ways to do this by using interop to Win32 functionality, but hopefully there is a WinUI 3 compatible library that can be used directly (such as System.Windows.Forms.Screen, which is used on Windows forms).

Thanks in advance for any advice that can be offered.

2/6 - checked out the link from Simon Mourier and tried out a ScreenCapture app that uses CreateForMonitor: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows.UI.Composition-Win32-Samples/tree/master/dotnet/WPF/ScreenCapture.  At this point, there would be quite some work to port this app to WinUI 3 as it is quite complex and uses interop for Direct3D functionality.  However, it is progress and I appreciate the response.

Comment: WinRT's GraphicsCaptureItem is the way to go, check the `CreateForMonitor` API and samples from here https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2019/09/16/new-ways-to-do-screen-capture/

Answer (score -2):

Winui3 applications have access to the [IGraphicsCaptureItemInterop interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windows.graphics.capture.interop/nn-windows-graphics-capture-interop-igraphicscaptureiteminterop). Here is a sample, I suggest you could refer to: https://github.com/robmikh/Win32CaptureSample

Comment: I tried out the Win32CaptureSample app.  It works well, but it is a Win32 C++ app and will have to be interop-ported to work within a WinUI3 app.  Do you know of a .NET porting of this app or some other app that uses the same Windows::Graphics::Capture API?  I appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: The WPF ScreenCapture app I mention in my 2/6 update above appears to be a derivative of Win32CaptureSample.

Comment: I suggest you could refer to the Doc: [Screen capture to video](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/screen-capture-video). And here is a sample: [Screen capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/screen-capture). You could try to use this in winui3.